# wordpress variable into shortcode

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode

i'm working on wordpress.
i have a function which add a category every time a user register:

```
add_action('user_register','username_insert_category');
function username_insert_category($user_id) {
   $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
   $usernameToLogin = $user_info->user_login;
     if (!empty($usernameToLogin) && !term_exists($usernameToLogin, glsr()->taxonomy)) {
            require_once ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php';
            wp_create_term($term, glsr()->taxonomy);
     }
 }
```

I need to use this category with the site review plugin.
The shortcode used to get all the reviews relative to a specific category is:

```
[site_reviews category={username} fallback="No reviews found."]
```

My issue is that in the page i have the category available with the variable {username} and if i try to make it work like that the shortcode get the review before reading the value (so it get all the reviews and not just the one relative to that category).

the shortcode works fine if i hard code the name of the category.

is there a way to make it work with the {username} variable?

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you putting the shortcode? Are you doing that inside of PHP code? Or in the WP editor somewhere? Can you also provide a link to the site_reviews plugin?

Comment: I am using it inside the WP editor. Here's the link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/site-reviews/  thanks

Comment: Is that your shortcode, or is it from the plugin Site Reviews plugin?

Comment: is from the plugin

Comment: According to the documentation of the site-reviews plugin, the category attribute of the shortcode only accepts a slug or ID. But why do you say that the variable `{username}` exists in your page? I don't really understand what that means and where that variable is coming from. Are you using this shortcode on a category page? I'm thinking that the `shortcode_atts_{$shortcode}` filter might help you if you want to make that username portion dynamic. But I think we need a bit more information first.

Comment: The variable {username} is available and it appears in the shortcode when i load the page. Unfortunately it does not load the relative reviews. Instead if i hard code the value (e.g.) example all the correct reviews are loaded. It's like the plugin charges the reviews and after load the value of {username}

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how that variable is 'available'. What do you mean when you say that?

Comment: That the correct value appears. the value {username} is loaded by another plugin. when i use {username} the correct value is shown in the page and also inside the shortcode ( i see it from the inspector)

Comment: I think the part that's missing is that you are seeing the `{username}` in your source, but that is because it's rendered. The username doesn't get passed into the shortcode because the shortcode is processed before that information is available.

Comment: I also agree with @Wesley-Synio, you will need to use the `shortcode_atts_` filter to pass that information to the shortcode.

Comment: I understand that... i know the shortcode is processed before the information is available... and that what i do not know how to do... how can i make it available to the shortcode

Comment: Which plugin loads the value `{username}`? I think this is what is confusing us. Maybe this gets rendered client-side. But I'm not sure how you can see the `{username}` in the shortcode either when viewing the page, because when viewing that page, the shortcode should already be rendered.. I think I'm missing or misunderstanding something crucial here.

Comment: the username is loaded by indeed membership pro plugin https://codecanyon.net/item/ultimate-membership-pro-wordpress-plugin/12159253. I'm not sure how can i see it but in the inspector i see the correct value... but then it load the wrong reviews

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you are seeing in Inspector?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/s9er6g

Comment: Looks like the site-reviews plugin renders everything through AJAX. Perhaps the `{username}` is modified too late (also in JS). I suggest you check the Network tab in developer tools of your browser to see what actually gets sent over the network to further debug this.

Comment: i'm a newby... and honestly i cannot find anything in the network tab. all i see are js and css... sorry... i know i'm not helping you to help me..